# Disable Query in Access with VBA

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

A coworker in accounting was complaining about how she ran a query twice and it doubled her values and she got confused. Im just a Junior IT person who has very little VBA experience. I am basically just trying to add code to make it so my queries in our databases can't be run more than once unless you restart the database. I was thinking of doing a boolean check to see if a query has been run and if it has don't allow it to be run again. Or maybe I could just do a simple if statement. Please let me know if you have any input on this issue.

I couldn't find anything on the Googs either.

Comment: Do you have anything Access can use to determine whether the query has been run during the current session?

Comment: I don't think Access has a built in function that can do that sadly. Thats what I wish I could code but I'm lousy at VB and couldn't find any similar scenarios when I googled. I need to run a check if its been run in the session and if it has, I need to lock it until a new session is created.

Comment: Use data macro's to copy to a table, to update a table, then check if there's an entry for that day.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct; there is no Access built-in feature to record when a query is run.  If your Access version is >= 2007 and if you prevent the user from running the query directly from the Navigation pane, you could load a `TempVar` to indicate when the query is run.  And at the next attempt, check the `TempVar` first to decide whether to proceed.  Note you would need to control how the user runs the query --- maybe from a command button on a form --- and use VBA to manage the `TempVar`, etc.

Comment: If I do that then wouldn't restrict me to a once a day use? I just want to have it to where its once a session, not once a day.

Comment: The data macro suggestion requires Access >= 2010.  Please clarify *"can't be run more than once unless you restart the database"*.  Does that mean only once per Access session or once per day.  Also, could more than one user run the query?  If so, how should that be managed?

Comment: Temp var will be dropped on closing i believe, what is it your query does, you could look at creating a PK that involves an ID, and session id, from a table incrementing or something like that.  So have PK of say Stock_ID AND SysSession where SysSession, could be sub query off the Sessions table, not incrementing until opening....  Access should then not allow ID_Session duplicated...  Just musing :)

Comment: A `TempVar` exists only in memory ... it disappears without a trace when you close Access.  So a `TempVar` could work for "once per session".

Comment: I would think on a date and a session ID as default values in each table, you could code the addition of both etc, and both of these are populated, date =date() and sessionID is the DMAX from your table, this table is incemented by a startup popup form, running macro, then the index of each table would be the date and the sessionID not allowing dupes.  You probably dont need the date, just a sessionID index.

Comment: What sort of query is this? SELECT / UPDATE / INSERT ? And how did it "doubled her values"? (where?) -- I have a hard time imagining a scenario where it would make sense to forbid this per session but not after a restart of the application.

Comment: She just sometimes accidently runs an update query I guess and she just wants it to where she can only run a query no more than once when she opens the customers' database. If she opens their database and runs a billing processing query and it appends fees to their invoice...she wants it to where she can't accidently do it again. SO I would have to have to make it where she would have to close out of access and restart access if she wanted to run a query a second time. 

If that makes sense Idk haha.

Answer (score 0):

I would think on a date and a session ID as default values in each table, you could code the addition of both etc.

These are populated, date =date() as default value and sessionID is the DMAX from your SessionID table, as extra column in said query.

This SessionID table is incemented by a startup popup form, running macro.

The Primary Key of each table being operated on would be the date and the sessionID not allowing dupes. You probably dont need the date, just a sessionID in the PK.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always the best idea to implement ad-hoc ideas by users like this.

You should analyze what happened here, and make sure it cannot happen in the application design, not by arbitrary rules.

Example: If the update query adds fees to a bill, and this must happen only once per bill, then the update query should also set a flag "fees added" in the bill record. And it should not update bills with this flag set.